# Adding Java game to my facebook wall

Tags: java, facebook

I have created a Java stand alone game.
I want to add it to my wall, Is it possible to do so?
What are the requirements? Does it must be a Java Applet?
Where can i find guide for developing Java games for FaceBook.
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already have your application written, but unfortunately, it's not a simple 2-minute process to get it uploaded to facebook.  Here's a good, 4-part, series of [tutorials](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/creating-a-facebook-app-setup-and-tool-installation/); nonetheless, I'm not entirely certain as to what you mean by *add it to my wall*.  You can upload and distribute, but...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider hosting the JAR file on a separate server, and providing a JNLP link on your wall.  I don't believe Facebook will allow an applet to run on your wall, even if you had one.

[Java Web Start (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an applet on Facebook. You would need to use Flash to create a game.

You could use REST in the front end Flash application to communicate with a backend Java server.

Comment: These are the Facebook reference APIs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

Comment: You do **not** have to use `Flash`.